# Loop complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, time-complexity

If I have the for loops below:

```
for(k = 1; k <= n; ++k){
    for(j = 1; j * j <= k; ++j){
        //O(1) operations
    }
}
```

I know the outer loop will iterate `n` times, and the inner loop will iterate `floor(sqrt(k))` for every `k`<sup>th</sup> iteration from outer loop.

Therfore,to determine the time complexity, we have something like, summation of

`\sum_{k=1}^{n} \floor{\sqrt{k}}`

Not sure how to proceed and get a closed form time complexity in terms of n.

Comment: A [google search](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65309.html) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you need to integrate sqrt(n) => n^(1/2). The result is n^(3/2). Forget about floor function.

Answer (score 0):

Outer loop is iterated `n` times, inner loop is iterated `sqrt(n)` times. When one loop is inside another loop you multiply their complexity. Therefore it runs in `O(n^1.5)`

Comment: "When one loop is inside another loop you multiply their complexity." - it's not as simple as that.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: How about this: "When one loop is inside another loop and they are mutually exclusive, you multiply their complexity"?

Comment: In this case they aren't.